# Give first duplicate a 1 and the rest 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data which contains 1000+ lines and in this it contains errors people make. I have added a extra column and would like to find all duplicate Rev Names and give the first one a 1 and all remaining duplicates a 0. When there is no duplicate, it should be a 1. The outcome should look like this:

```
RevName   ErrorCount    Duplicate 
Rev5588   23            1
Rev5588   67            0
Rev5588   7             0
Rev5588   45            0
Rev7895   6             1
Rev9065   4             1
Rev5588   1             1
```

I have tried CASE WHEN but its not giving the first one a 1, its giving them all zero's.

Thanks guys, I am pulling out my hair here trying to get this done.

Comment: You need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression over the `row_number` window function:

```
SELECT RevName,
       Duplicate,
       CASE ROW_NUMER() OVER (PARTITION BY RevName
                              ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Duplicate
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" of anything, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Your logic suggests `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(revname) over (order by ??) = revname then 0
             else 1
        end) as is_duplicate
from t;
```

The `??` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: there is not really anything unique to order it by, somebody creates a whole bunch of errors at the same time. what i want here is when there is a duplicate bunch, any one of the duplicates must be a 1.